Ubuntu 24.04.1 main ui windows: control panel, launchpad, etc expand and shrink when l click on them
I recently installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS on my Thinkpad Yoga X1 Gen 6. As I’m not a fan of the default top bar, I added the GNOME Dash to Panel extension. However, the dock was still visible on the lock screen, so I ran
sudo apt upgrade

After this, Ubuntu's main control UI elements started behaving oddly—when I try to open the Control Panel or Launchpad, the windows close almost immediately, as if I’m double-clicking rapidly, even though I'm only clicking once.

